# having an issue saving NLog file to basefolder

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm having a hard time understanding why `${basedir}` does nothing to the current directory of the project and when I change it to the explicit path it does saves the log.
I tried to change the name of `${basedir}` to `${currentdir}` but it did nothing.

**This one works**

```
  <target xsi:type="File" name="myAppLoggerTarget" fileName="C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\DBBalancers\Logs\${shortdate}.log"
         layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

**This one works**

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="myAppLoggerTarget" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by `${basedir} does nothing to the current directory of the project` ? And can you explain what filepath is wanted?

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Basedir-Layout-Renderer) to nlog docs suggests: "The current application domain's base directory."

I would try to print out the: "[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-5.0)" and see whats the value of that variable.

On the same nlog docs page you can also find about process dir:
processDir - Introduced in NLog 4.4.2. Render the base directory of the current process? Default false.